# Calling a virtual function from a derived pointer without paying the vtable price

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism, vtable

Considering this simple example:

```
class Base {
    virtual void foo() {};  
};

class Derived: public Base {
    void foo() {}; 
}; 

Base    *b = new Derived;
Derived *d = new Derived;
b->foo();
d->foo();
```

My question is: does a call to a member function declared as virtual in a base class (but not in the derived class) through a derived class pointer uses (and pay the price for) the vtable mechanism ? In the example `b->foo()` uses the vtable mechanism to call the `Derived::foo()`, but `d->foo()`?

If yes, how circumvent this behavior: when using explicitly a `Derived` pointer, I would like to directly call the `Derived::foo()` method without paying the cost of the vtable, as if the base class does not exist?

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? *Why* do you want to sidestep the vtable lookup? And have you *measured* that this is a serious bottleneck in your application? It's not just premature optimization because of something you heard or read?

Comment: If you want to be sure that classes inheriting from `Derived` does not override `foo`, you can use the [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) keyword. If you do so, the compiler will probably optimise out the vtable lookup when calling `foo()` on a `Derived*`.

Comment: I thought about this final keyword, but how to check if the optimizer actually skip the vtable?

Comment: Compilers try to optimize virtual dispatch and remove the indirection if possible. Gcc has been much improved in this direction. You can read a lot about it in a great series of articles from one of the gcc developers: https://hubicka.blogspot.de/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html

Comment: If you are doing this is an optimization, I really hope that you have measured thoruoughly to prove that is a hotspot. If not, I would really advice to profile before doing anything like this.

Comment: "I thought about this final keyword, but how to check if the optimizer actually skip the vtable?" Check out the generated assembly code for this.

Comment: What is your real code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax

```
d->Derived::foo();
```

will suppress virtual dispatch and guarantee that the function `Derived::foo` is the one called, even in the presence of overriding functions.

This is rarely what you want, but I cannot suggest alternative solutions unless you explain why you're trying to do this. For example, in the code snippet given, there is no reason why the `Derived` should be dynamically allocated at all. You could just write this instead:

```
Derived d;
d.foo();
```

Here, the compiler knows for sure that the dynamic type is `Derived`, so no virtual dispatch is needed.

Answer (score 2):

> does a call to a member function declared as virtual in a base class (but not in the deverived class)...

I've stopped to read here, because if `Base` declare `foo` as virtual, `Derived` can only override `foo`, `Derived::foo` (supposedly signature match) **is implicitly `virtual`**.

The following definitions of `Derived::foo` are *identical*:

```
class Derived: public Base {
  void foo() {}; 
};

class Derived: public Base {
  virtual void foo() {}; 
};
```

---

This mechanism is called implicit virtual propagation, and [this SO answer tries and explain why id was conceived that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087242/5470596). Here is the rationale about it:

> **10.3 Virtual functions**
>
> 2 If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (**whether or not it is so declared**) and it overrides `Base::vf`.

Comment: Ok, so my question now is: how to circumvent that?

Comment: @janou195 You circumvent it using the trick shown in Brian's answer. But this would no longer respect the expected semantics nor the Open/Closed principle: If `d` would point to an object of `class TwiceDerived : public Derived` with is own special function implementation you would ignore this specialization and still call `Derived::foo()`.  Sooner or later, this will create havoc (e.g. if `Derived::foo()` and `TwiceDerived::foo()`are using different assumptions to downcast member pointers of other types).     If you're so concerned about performance, use non virtual members instead