# C++ Why does an interface connects non-virtual classes overrides?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I would like to better understand how the `virtual` qualifier is propagated in a class family. Consider the following code:

```
struct Parent {
  void func() { cout << "Parent!" << endl; }
};

struct Child : Parent {
  void func() { cout << "Child!" << endl; }
};

int main() {  
  Parent* pc = new Child;
  pc->func(); // prints "Parent!"
}
```

The `Child` override of `func()` is not called because the `Parent` function is not `virtual`. Simple enough.

In the following example, I added an interface to `Parent` and  I don't understand why adding it bound the call from `Parent::func()` to `Child:func()` since this last one is called from a `Parent` pointer.

```
struct Interface {
  virtual void func() = 0;
};

struct Parent : Interface {
  void func() { cout << "Parent!" << endl; }
};

struct Child : Parent {
  void func() { cout << "Child!" << endl; }
};

int main() {  
  Parent* pc = new Child;
  pc->func(); // prints "Child!"
}
```

I was thinking that the construction of `new Child` would go in the following order :

1. `Interface` in constructed, declaring a pure virtual `func()`
2. `Parent` is constructed, overriding `func()` (I thought that at this point, the abstract construction would be "satisfied" and "done")
3. `Child` is constructed, declaring it's own `func()`implementation

Comment: the method is virtual in `Child` also, methods do not need the `virtual` keyword to be virtual, but only the base has to declare it as virtual. ...trying to find the duplicate

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972462/why-is-the-virtuality-of-methods-implicitly-propagated-in-c?rq=1

Comment: this is what I was looking for, unfortunately not really a good duplicate, but maybe good enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary

Comment: Use [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) when you mean to override a `virtual` function. If it compiles then you actually did override. Otherwise the compiler will complain that you used `override` without overriding anything. It makes this type of code more readable, especially when you have `-Werror=suggest-override` to enforce that style.